# Laravel If Else statement inside foreach

Tags: if-statement, foreach, domdocument, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use if/else statement inside my foreach loop. 
With DomDocument i'm trying to find the description tag and the inside of the description tag.

This works fine. When there is a description tag, it display's what's inside the description tag. If there is no description tag it displays: `No description found No description found No description found No description found`. Why does it show the error four times? How do i fix this?

I'm using **DomDocument and Laravel 5.4**

Meta tag:

```
$meta = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

My code:

```
@foreach ($meta as $node)
  @if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description') 
    {{$node->getAttribute('content'), PHP_EOL}}
      @else 
       {{'No description found'}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

**Edit, according to Muthu17:**

I have almost written the same code as you. But the only problem is: It shows "No description found" all the time. Even if it finds the description tag, it show's the description tag init and "No description found".

I've declared the `$showErrorMessage = 0;` in my controller.

```
@foreach ($meta as $node)
 @if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description') 
  {{$node->getAttribute('content'), PHP_EOL}}
   @else
    {!! $showErrorMessage == 1; !!}
   @endif
@endforeach

@if($showErrorMessage = 1)
 {{'No description found'}}
@endif
```

Comment: what does {{$node}} give?

Comment: Your loop contains 3 items, and the three items does not have description, So you are getting 'No description found' message 3 times

Comment: @pseudoanime Thanks for asking. I've updated my post!

Comment: @muthu17 I figured that, but how do i fix this?

Comment: Before for each create one varaibale for eg : showErrorMessage  = 0 and inside else just chage the  value to 1 [ showErrorMessage  = 0 ] after for each ends check showErrorMessage status and print the message

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking something like this

```
<?php $showErrorMessage = 0; ?>
@foreach ($meta as $node)
  @if($node->getAttribute('name')=='description') 
    {{$node->getAttribute('content'), PHP_EOL}}
      @else 
       <?php $showErrorMessage = 1;?>
  @endif
@endforeach

@if($showErrorMessage == 0)
 {{'No description found'}}
@endif
```

Comment: I've updated my post with my changes. Can you take a look at those?

Comment: You should not give {!! $showErrorMessage == 1; !!}, It should be {!! $showErrorMessage = 1; !!}

Comment: Should not give == for asigning the values to variables, You should use == only at checking the conditions.

Comment: And Change @if($showErrorMessage = 1) to @if($showErrorMessage == 1)